# Add/remove content on click button via jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to do a webpage in which when I will press a button it will remove any content inside a div and it will add as html code the iframe bellow into a div

```
<iframe id="a" 

src="link1" width="640" height="360" 

frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" 

mozallowfullscreen="" oallowfullscreen="" msallowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

When I ll press another button it will remove the code inside from div and it will add another code as bellow

```
<embed id="b" src="link2" type="application/x-mplayer2" 

width="200" height="70" autostart="1" align="center" border="0" transparentatstart="0" 

animationatstart="1" showcontrols="true" showaudiocontrols="1" showpositioncontrols="0" 

showtracker="0" autosize="0" showstatusbar="1" displaysize="false">
```

And there is the main page as example

```
<div id="content"></div>
<input type="button" value="Value1">
<input type="button" value="Value2">
```

Comment: Please show any code you have tried.

Comment: I tried with simple Javascript. But because I want it only for local page it doesn't work. So, I m looking for jQuery solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, add some `id`'s to your buttons:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Value1">
<input id="button2" type="button" value="Value2">
```

Add `click` handlers for each button:

```
//when `button1` is clicked
$('#button1').click( function() { 

  //remove the contents of the #content div
  $('#content').contents().remove();

  //use append to insert content into the #content div
  $('#content').append('<iframe id="a" src="link1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" oallowfullscreen="" msallowfullscreen=""></iframe>');

});

//when 'button2' is clicked
$('#button2').click( function() { 

  //remove the contents of the #content div
  $('#content').contents().remove();

  //add the other content that you specified to the #content div
  $('#content').append('<embed id="b" src="link2" type="application/x-mplayer2" width="200" height="70" autostart="1" align="center" border="0" transparentatstart="0" animationatstart="1" showcontrols="true" showaudiocontrols="1" showpositioncontrols="0" showtracker="0" autosize="0" showstatusbar="1" displaysize="false">');

});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I m checking the iframe at least. http://jsfiddle.net/hnf26xdx/2/

Comment: I see. I didn't realize you wanted to remove content when clicking either of the buttons. Answer is updated to show that.